# Need alternative for toJavaDatePattern method from HsqlDateTime class from jar - hsqldb-2.3.1

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, hsqldb, date-formatting

Need alternative for toJavaDatePattern method which is available in `HsqlDateTime` class from `jar - hsqldb-2.3.1.`

Method usage - Converts the given format to pattern acceptable by SimpleDateFormat.

Example:
`toJavaDatePattern("DD-MON-YYYY")`  - This returns - `dd-MMM-yyyy`

I need to achieve the same thing and don't use this method.

Comment: I definitely recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That is a notorious troublemaker of a class and long outdated. Use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Most of the format pattern letters are the same, not all of them. For example, with `DateTimeFormatter` you can choose between `dd-MMM-uuuu` and `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Comment: I know of no other library method with same functionality. If you know the HSQL format syntax, you should be able to code it yourself. It’s not clear to me whether you are asking if the method exists or if someone will write it for you? Both seem to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can improve your question by spelling out what your search engine turned up and/or what your own attempt at writing the method looks like.

Comment: Also what do you need this for? Asking because I believe that your JDBC driver can transfer `LocalDate` and other java.time objects to and from the database, and you should avoid passing dates back and forth as strings.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need this so I can add any date format as param and get back the SimpleDateFormat for given date format in param.

Comment: It seems that the source code of the method is [on Github](https://github.com/ryenus/hsqldb/blob/master/src/org/hsqldb/HsqlDateTime.java) from line 663. Maybe you can copy-paste it from there??

Comment: Source code is now here on Github [link](https://github.com/ryenus/hsqldb/blob/master/src/org/hsqldb/types/HsqlDateTime.java).